# how to make a Powershell script avaiable from anywhere

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a Powershell script I would like to make "public", meaning I want to be able to execute the script from any folder as you can do from the command prompt.

Is this possible?

Comment: add it to one of the directories in your path ... that is how windows/dos/cmd/bat does it ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explore the use of your powershell profile to achieve this. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles.

If the script is just a function or some variables, you can copy and paste the content into your profile.

Alternatively, if the script represents a standalone unit of code you want to keep separate, you could import it into your main profile as such:

```
get-content -path C:\blahblahblah\scriptName.ps1 -raw | invoke-expression
```

Finally, if you are writing an "advanced" powershell function, or are trying to do things officially, you could investigate the use of powershell modules as a way to export your function. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules

@Lee_Dailey's answer of adding the script to your path is also viable. If you want to add a lot of scripts, one way to do that is to add a folder like `C:/PowershellScripts/`, to your path, save your scripts there, and then you'll be able to invoke your .PS1 file from anywhere.

Comment: Helpful, but note that you should use `.` (the dot-sourcing) operator in order to add a `.ps1` file's definitions (functions, aliases, variables) to the caller's scope (which is the _global_ scope when executed from `$PROFILE`); [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). The use of _advanced functions_ is technically unrelated to _modules_, though it makes sense to make all functions you export from a module advanced ones.

Answer (score 6):

You can also add an alias in your local powershell profile

## Alias Example in profile

Set-Alias hello C:\scriptlocation\script.ps1

Now anytime you type hello, the script.ps1 will run.

More info on the various profiles that the alias can be saved to.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/

Comment: Do I have to put _C:\scriptlocation\script.ps1_ in an environnement variable? I execute your comand, but when It isn't persistent. When I close window and reopen, alias doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Name the script something meaningful ie: `awesome.bat` Save it in a dir and add the dir to windows env. Command `awesome` will be globally available.

Comment: Actually, you can add the `.ps1` script to that directory and call it anywhere, no need to the `bat` stuff